# How to unit test if consumer ran successfully in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

Im trying to write a unit test that should validate if a consumer ran or not.
But for some reason the consumer never executes.

I have created a more simplified version of the problem using the Getting-Started-sample of MassTransit.

This is "my" code:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private ITestHarness _testHarness;
    
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        serviceCollection.AddMassTransitTestHarness(busRegistrationConfigurator =>
        {
            busRegistrationConfigurator.AddConsumer<MessageConsumer>();
        });

        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        _testHarness = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();
    }
    
    
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        await _testHarness.Bus.Publish(new Message { Text = "Hello, world!" });
        (await _testHarness.Published.Any<Message>()).Should().BeTrue();
        (await _testHarness.Consumed.Any<Message>()).Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```

The following assertion:

```
(await _testHarness.Consumed.Any<Message>()).Should().BeTrue();
```

Fails, since it always returns False.

I guess that I somehow need to await the consumer to execute? And I might be missing even more..

Been having a look at the documentations of MassTransit regarding testing, but Im not sure if the sample provided in the docs apply to this scenario (?), since the sample provided involves a request and response.

Would very much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing one line:

`await _testHarness.Start();`

Of course, you'll need to be sure and *Dispose* the container to ensure the bus is stopped and cleaned up.